# Backbone - fetched model, set an attribute(modify), then save model, it should update but sending POST request

Tags: backbone.js

I created my web site having 2 types of users: admin and user. So, I created 3 pages `mainpag.html`, `admin.html`, `user.html`. and separate models, views, collections, `routers.js` files for each of them. After logging in, as I am sending users to separate HTML pages with different models, I can't automatically get user model. so I did like this:

First, I made AJAX call to server, asking for the `_id` (username in session, so I can get id)

from the id, I fetched the model, by `model.fetch()`, then I got my usermodel with all attributes.

then in the success callback of fetch, I did `model.save({weight: "somevalue"})`. According to me, it should update right, as the model is already available, that attribute weight also available with some old value, but it is sending POST request, also when I tried `model.isNew()`, it returned true. Where am I wrong? how can I update my model? I will post more details if required.

More details:

If I remove that save method, then I am getting correct attributes in the model.

If I don't remove that save method, that success and error callbacks are also appearing as attributes in the model.

Code:

```
   addWeight : (e)->
    arr=new Array()
    arr['_id']=app._id
    console.log "asdasd"
    console.log arr
    console.log arr['_id']
    @user_model =new UserModel(arr)
    @user_model.fetch({
      success : (model,res,options) =>
        console.log model
        console.log res
        arr=new Array()
        arr['_id']=e.target.id
        #arr['action']='weight' #means , update weight
        #@user_model.setArr(arr)
        #@user_model.set({weight : arr['_id']})
        console.log "new  : "+@user_model.isNew()
        @user_model.save({weight : e.target.id})
        #@user_model.save({
        #  success : (model,res,options) =>
        #    console.log "model updated: "+JSON.stringify(model)
        #    console.log "Res : "+JSON.stringify(res)
        #  error : (model,res,options) =>
        #    console.log "Error : "+JSON.stringify(res)
        #})

      error : (model,res,options) =>
        console.log "Error "

    })
```

the above code is written in coffeescript, so even if you don't know coffeescript, don't worry, you can understand easily, and those `#` mean, it is a comment. here we follow indentation instead of braces.

one more doubt, a model's URL must be changed dynamically according to the requirement, right? what is the best way to achieve that? I am doing like this:

I am populating "array" containing the required fields that should be present in the URL. In model, s init func, I am using `@arr=arr`, then in URLs function, I check like this.

```
   url : ->
     if @arr['id']
     "/user/#{@id}"
```

Is my approach right, or any better approach is there for dynamically setting URLs. Or can I directly set the URLs like this:

```
    @user_model.setUrl "/someurl/someid"  //this setUrl method is available in model's definition
    @user_model.fetch() or save() or watever that needs url
```

Answer (score 3):

Just a hunch, but you mentioned that you call `model.fetch()` to retrieve the `_id` field. Be sure to either return an `id` field instead `_id` (notice the underscore).

The call to `model.isNew()` returning `true` is an indicator that the `id` property was never set from the `model.fetch()` call.

I look forward to a possible further explanation with your code...
Looking at your code:

```
/* The model needs an 'id' attribute in order to marked as not new */ 
@user_model = new UserModel(id: arr['_id'])
```

Comment: Mhm, that's what I thought too

Comment: Yep! He should use `idAttribute: '_id'`

Comment: @KalebF. i added more in the question at the end , regarding managing url dynamically, please see that

Answer (score 2):

Actually if you call

```
model.set({weight: "somevalue"});
```

It will update the value in the model, but it won't send a POST request

```
model.save(attribute);
```

Actually calls Backbone.sync as you probably know.

EDIT :

You might want ot set

```
m = Backbone.Model.extend({
    idAttribute: '_id'
});
```

to every model, because the isNew method actually checks if the model has id attribute

Regarding to this you could see here that .set doesn't call backbone.sync here : http://jsfiddle.net/5M9HH/1/

Comment: i tried that also, it is sending post request,thats my problem, anyway, i will post my code in 2min..]

Comment: just got an idea, model is considered as new if it dont have "id" property, here i dont have "id" property, i have "_id" property,, my database uses "_id" as default , so i am using that . so is that the problem here ?

Comment: i added more in the question, regarding dynamically managing models url, please see that

Comment: Use `model.urlRoot` for this and write seperate question ;)